# finding the probability event that corresponds to an integration

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Assuming we have 2 independent random variables, $X$ and $Y$. What is the probability event $A$ that corresponds to the following integration?

$\Pr (A) = \int_{-\infty}^{t} f_{Y} (y) F_{X}(y) dy$
where $F_{X}$ is the CDF of $X$ and $f_{Y}$ is the PDF of $Y$

Comment: Assuming that $X$ and $Y$ are _jointly continuous_ random variables, write $F_X(y)$ as $\int_{-\infty}^y f_X(x)\, \mathrm dx$ and then $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = f_X(x)f_Y(y)$. What region does the double integral correspond to?

Comment: @DilipSarwate according to the comments below, the region for the double integral is $(-\infty,y) $ and $(-\infty,t)$. What confuses me now is that what if I start by integrating with respect to y first, I would integrate from $(x,t)$ because $y>x$, but then what will be the region for the outer integral for x ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If in this situation $Y$ has a PDF then:

$$\begin{aligned}P\left(X\leq Y\leq t\right) & =\int f_{Y}\left(y\right)P\left(X\leq Y\leq t\mid Y=y\right)dy\\
 & =\int f_{Y}\left(y\right)P\left(X\leq y\leq t\right)dy\\
 & =\int_{-\infty}^{t}f_{Y}\left(y\right)P\left(X\leq y\right)dy\\
 & =\int_{-\infty}^{t}f_{Y}\left(y\right)F_{X}\left(y\right)dy
\end{aligned}
$$

The second equality is based on independence of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: Can we write this event in the form of a Cartesian product of two sets?

Comment: That is a question that concerns the underlying probability space and any info about that space lacks. Why are you interested in that question?

Comment: I have proved so far that   
$Pr( X^{-1} \{y|y\le t_{x}\}\  \times \ Y^{-1} \{ y|y\le t \wedge y=t_{x}\}) = \int _{-\infty} ^{t} f_{y}(y) * F_{X} (t_{x}) dy$   
my problem is that the $F_{X} (t_{x})$ is independent of the integral which is considered as a constant, and it should be a function of $y$ so that it stays inside the integral.   
I think that the event that I constructed for this integration is not the right event.

Comment: $Y^{-1}\{y\mid y\leq t\wedge y=t_x\}=\{Y\leq t\wedge Y=t_x\}\subseteq\{Y=t_x\}$ so $P(Y^{-1}\{y\mid y\leq t\wedge y=t_x\})\leq P(Y=t_x)=0$. Consequently $P(\{X\leq t_x\}\times\{Y\leq t\wedge Y=t_x\})=P(\{X\leq t_x\})\times P(\{Y\leq t\wedge Y=t_x\})=0$. No idea what you meant with $t_x$.

Comment: but what if $t_{x} \le t$ ? this will not make $\{Y \le t \wedge Y = t_{x} \}$ a subset of $ \{Y = t_{x}\} $. 

$t_{x}$ is any intermediate value between $-\infty$ and $t$

Comment: $\omega\in\{Y\leq t\wedge Y=t_x\}\implies Y(\omega)=t_x\implies\omega\in\{Y=t_x\}$ so $\{Y\leq t\wedge Y=t_x\}\subseteq\{Y=t_x\}$. This is not depending on the question whether $t_x\leq t$ or $t_x>t$. It is simply always true.

Comment: thanx for your prompt replies. I understand your point. 
How can I express this form $ (X \le Y\le t)$ to its equivalent set form? so that I can derive using the probability theory properties from this set form to this integration

Comment: Expression $X\leq Y\leq t$ corresponds with event $\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X(\omega)\leq Y(\omega)\leq t\}$ where $\Omega$ denotes the underlying [sample space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_space) which on its turn is an essential part of underlying [probability space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_space) $\langle\Omega,\mathcal A,P\rangle$. It is unclear to me though what you are after. In fact we have $A=\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X(\omega)\leq Y(\omega)\leq t\}\in\mathcal A$ for the $A$ mentioned in your question.

Comment: I need to express the event in the real line so that it will correspond to an event in the probability space. for example:
$P (X^{-1} (A) ) = \int \textbf{1} _{A} dF_{X} $
in my case I have two random variables, and the set A will be in the form of a cross product of two sets, each of which corresponds to a random variable